# What loss criterion does CARET's random forest use?

Tags: r, random-forest, gini

What is the default loss criterion that CARET's random forest uses for classification (e.g. gini, entropy, log-loss)?

In scikit-learn, `gini` is the default loss function of the random forest ([source](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html)). However, I cannot find what the default loss function is for CARET's random forest. I checked the CARET [source code](https://github.com/topepo/caret/tree/master) and [documentation](https://topepo.github.io/caret/train-models-by-tag.html#random-forest), but could not find a clear answer there. Any suggestions would be really helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you doing a regression or classification? It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input that can be used to test and verify possible answers and make it clear exactly how you are calling the function.

Comment: I suspect that you might be more likely to find someone who knows this on [STATS.SE] instead